# Facebook connect, email address?

Tags: facebook

When you add facebook connect to allow facebook users to signin to your site, can you retireve the users name and email addresss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to prompt them for data permission "email" first though. Facebook is also changing the way you can get access to private data very soon (hell, they change their API and policies daily; who can keep up). Check out the following links for more:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/upgrade#permissions

You'll want to add the list of permissions you want to prompt for in the login:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login

Answer (score 3):

You can get name right after user connected, but the answer "how to do this" is depends on what type of integration do you use - "old" or "Graph", and which technology - JS, php, python, c#, etc

Email can be retrieved just after you granted the [extended email permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions). The common way to grant this permission is to ask it during the connection process, that is well described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)