# Facebook graph api problem

Tags: php, facebook

iam using openid for login in my site, and upon successful login, i could get the user's email and other parameters like first name.

But for facebook, iam using facebook connect (Graph api) and after successful login, iam getting an access token. But using this token, iam not able to fetch the user's email. I end up with an error saying either invalid token or invalid redirect url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook connect, email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986578/facebook-connect-email-address)

Comment: no, i think its not a duplicate, because iam getting an error here. I also changed the title now. Please see.

Comment: what extended permissions do you request ?

Comment: I used: 
header('Location: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=167276576646847&redirect_uri=http://my_site.com/user_login.php&client_secret=jvf983hs72943774&type=client_cred&code=2.BmEDugiE359VJBlIe70cbw__.3600.1293523200-588574303|fHN9R3PXxPsXjKTdkzFSJt8IN5U');

and when i got an access token, i raised another request:
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=16728383847|dnsan3499sadsad9ddnsand_xAI

But then, i got an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Comment: It seems some problem with either the graph api or my application settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get your initial token, you must redirect the user to the login URL requesting the permissions you want, in this case, "email". The easiest way to implement this is using the PHP SDK provided by Facebook.

If the user grants the permissions, you'll be able to query the graph api to get the email address (along with other basic information.) Once you have a valid working token and the user has authorized your application, the email address will be included $user_data.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>APP_ID, 'secret'=>APP_SECRET, 'cookie'=>true));

try{
   $user_data = $facebook->api('/me'); 
} catch (Exception $e){ 
   header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('perms'=>'email'));
   die();
}

print $user_data['email'];
```

Be aware that the email address **may** be a proxy address and be much longer than a typical email address so allocate sufficient space in your storage system. For example, the address might look something like this: apps+2356396727.745.22667a3160x3d6wd2c1396c4efd7277b@proxymail.facebook.com